# Using a common object between different stages of execution from Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am working in an Azure function app development. There are different project dependencies as well. The business logic is implemented at application layer.

Environment: .NET 6

The function does different tasks such as

- generate a transaction ID
- Fetch data from Db based on an input parameter
- Transform the data
- Write the transformed data into DB
- Write the transformed data into service bus topic

When all these steps finishes, it needs to write the log into a service bus queue.
Also the execution happens at function level as well as application layer

For example the ID created immediately when Azure function being hit. Tranformation happens at application layer project.

But I need to hold all these information into a single object and that object I am going to write into a service bus queue as a JSON message.

Here is my class definition.

```
Public class ServiceMessage
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int ProcessId { get; set; }

    public object? ProcessExecutionId { get; set; }

    public string? PrimaryObjectName { get; set; }

    public string? ServiceName { get; set; }

    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public List<Message>? Message { get; set; }
}
public sealed class Message
{

    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public string? Remarks { get; set; }

    public string? Timestamp { get; set; }

}
public enum Status
{
    Failure = 0,
    InProgress = 1,
    Success = 2
}
```

While application progressing, I need to set each of these properties. Also there is a Message Array which is for holding any specific messages/error while any stages of the processing.

I dont know how to handle this situation.

I thought about declaring an object initially and passing the same object to different methods and there it got updated and that methods return back the object and the same for everywhere. But I believe its a bad approach.

Could you please help me to handle this.

Comment: _"But I believe its a bad approach."_ - why do you believe that?

Comment: I was assuming its not a great approach.. of passing the object all across the methods along with that methods other parameters if there are many already..

Comment: You mean someting along these lines: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7soZNs ?

Comment: Yes, So if method1 has already 4-5 parameters we have to pass this as the 6th one, isnt it? What I thought is like some static object..

Comment: With static objects you always need to be careful about concurrent access. Will functions run in parallel? Will they try to access the same static object at the same time? Will they overwrite each other's data?